# Subtract series value from pandas data frame given multiple index

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, subtraction

I have a big data frame in Pandas, *table A*, with structure like below:

```
key1   key2     value1 
1      201501     12      
2      201502     4     
3      201503     3      
4      201506     9      
5      201507     15
6      201509     nan
```

from *table A*, colum *value1*, I want to subtract *value2* from *table B* with apperance like below, using *key1* and *key2* as joining keys:

```
key1   key2     value2 
1      201501     11      
3      201503     2
5      201507     14
```

I want the the following in *table A*:

```
key1   key2     value1 
1      201501     1      
2      201502     4     
3      201503     1      
4      201506     9      
5      201507     1
6      201509     nan
```

How can I achieve this in a super efficient way? Today I join together the two tables and substrat *value1* in `A` with *value2* from `B`, my questions is if this can be done in a smarter pythonic "look-up" fashion which is more sleek and compact?

Data Frame code below

```
import numpy as np

tableA= pd.DataFrame({'key1':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                'key2':[201501,201502,201503,201506,201507,201509],
                'value1':[12,4,3,9,15,np.nan]
                })



tableB= pd.DataFrame({'key1':[1,3,5],
                'key2':[201501,201503,201507],
                'value1':[11,2,14]
                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tableA.set_index(keys).value1 \
    .sub(tableB.set_index(keys).value1, fill_value=0) \
    .reset_index()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create `DataFrames` with `MultiIndexes` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then substract by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) by first `DataFrame`:

```
print (tableA.set_index(['key1','key2'])
             .sub(tableB.set_index(['key1','key2']))
             .fillna(tableA.set_index(['key1','key2']))
             .reset_index())

   key1    key2  value1
0     1  201501     1.0
1     2  201502     4.0
2     3  201503     1.0
3     4  201506     9.0
4     5  201507     1.0
5     6  201509     NaN
```

Another solution with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
print (tableA.set_index(['key1','key2'])
             .sub(tableB.set_index(['key1','key2']))
             .combine_first(tableA.set_index(['key1','key2']))
             .reset_index())

   key1    key2  value1
0     1  201501     1.0
1     2  201502     4.0
2     3  201503     1.0
3     4  201506     9.0
4     5  201507     1.0
5     6  201509     NaN
```

Comment: Does above hold true if table A contains multiple columns, apart from the three specified?

Comment: Then use another `piRSquared`'s solution.